# timestamp object not changed but coming under hibernate dirty check

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to update one of the field(cityName) in my table,while doing so, it also updating other field(auditTimeStamp) with type of timestamp is updating as current time stamp..

while gone thorugh the logs, we found both objects(cityName,auditTimeStamp) are coming under hibernate dirty check creteria...

```
<class name= "Address"
        table="ADR_TB" dynamic-insert="true" dynamic-update="true" select-before-update="true">

<property name="cityName" column="G_CITY_NAM" type="java.lang.String"/>
<property name="auditTimeStamp" column="G_AUD_TS" type="timestamp"/>
```

pls let me know why it is updating auditTimeStamp field..??

Comment: Probably because you have some code, somewhere, updating the audit timestamp every time an entity is modified. Isn't that the point of this timestamp?

Comment: my code is very simple Nizet...it is like au.getAddress().setCityName("test111"); session.saveOrUpdate(au);

Comment: Yes, but that is not your whole code. You also have an Address entity, code configuring Hibernate and creating a SessionFactory, potentially registering listeners. Somewhere in that code, I suspect something updates the timestamp every time the entity is updated, because that's probably the whole point of this timestamp.

Comment: @JBNizet: Is there any table level configuration like trigger for the field, would make that field modified on the table update..? i checked there is no trigger on that table.. any other possiblities..?  pls help on this..